# Shiny Leaflet - hiding/removing legend

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I have a R shiny-app which shows election results on a map using javascript library leaflet.

Initially, the map fill is based on winning party (a **categorical variable**). The user can switch too see the demographics (a **continuous variable**). I am able to get both the maps. But when leafletproxy is changing fill property of maps as requested by user, the legend of the previous map is not overwritten and instead the new legend comes on top of the previous legend. ***How can I remove legends in leaflet in R***?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use..

```
leafletProxy("map") %>%
clearControls()
```

Before re-plotting and adding back in the legend.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: If you want to remove just a single legend (for example if you have scales and other legends) you can use `removeControl(map, layerId)`